# UICollectionView cell reusability issues

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, gallery

I'm making a simple gallery iOS program and have a question regarding UICollectionView datasource behavior.

Everything works fine in my code except that the image of each cell flickers when I scroll up or down.

1. Invisible cells do not download images before they become visible. 
   In my code, it is downloading on demand. Is this a best practice? Is this the reason why I get flickered cells?
2. Reusability of cells is confusing to me. In my observation, a cell loses its own image when it becomes invisible. How can I prevent this? Is this also the reason why I get flickered cells?

Here is the code.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        FBPhotoCollectionViewCell *cell = (FBPhotoCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        __weak FBPhotosVC *weakSelf = self;

        if ([_PhotoLinks count] > 0) {
               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{


        NSURL* theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[_PhotoLinks objectAtIndex:(int)indexPath.row]];
        UIImage* tempImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:theURL]];

        if ([weakSelf.theCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems containsObject:indexPath]) {

            if (tempImage)
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    FBPhotoCollectionViewCell *cell = (FBPhotoCollectionViewCell *)[weakSelf.theCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    cell.theImageView.image = tempImage;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                // Download failed.
                NSLog(@"Downloaded image is nil.");
            }
        }
    });
}

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]; <br>
return cell; <br>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this :

```
if ([weakSelf.theCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems containsObject:indexPath])
```

You don't have to check if the cell is visible or not. cellForItemAtIndexPath is only called when a new cell becomes visible, and when this cell disappears from the screen it gets reused.

Also I don't think you really need multithreading to load images like that. Try removing it two.

What you could do is store the images you already downloaded in an array or dictionnary and check it every time cellForItemAtIndexPath is called.

```
(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FBPhotoCollectionViewCell cell = (FBPhotoCollectionViewCell)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([_PhotoLinks count] > 0) 
    { 
        NSString photoName = [_PhotoLinks objectAtIndex:(int)indexPath.row];
        UIImage* tempImage = [self.cacheDictionnary objectForKey:photoName];

        if (!tempImage)
        {
            NSURL* theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:photoName];
            tempImage= [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:theURL]];
        }

        if (tempImage)
        {
            [self.cacheDictionnary setObject:tempImage forKey:photoName];
            cell.theImageView.image = tempImage;
        }
        else
        {
            // Download failed.
            NSLog(@"Downloaded image is nil.");
        }
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TrainingGoalsCell *cell = (TrainingGoalsCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

```
NSString *thePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[arrayVideos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:thePath];



CGRect attachmentFrame = CGRectMake(2, 2, cell.frame.size.width-4, cell.frame.size.height-4);

if(!isScrolling){
UIView* subView;
// asset is a video
    self.avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
    self.avPlayer.muted = YES;
    self.avPlayerLayer =[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
    [self.avPlayerLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width-4, cell.frame.size.height-4)];

    if(!subView){
    subView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:attachmentFrame];
    [subView.layer addSublayer:self.avPlayerLayer];
    [[cell.contentView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:subView];
    }

    [self.avPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
    self.avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    [self.avPlayer play];

    self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[self.avPlayer currentItem]];
}
```